# How should I mention any experience I have with children that isn't formal work experience on my CV/resume?

Tags: resume

I am applying for jobs that require me to work with children. I have no formal work experience in working with children, but I have a lot of nephews and nieces and because of this I'm very comfortable and quite capable around children.

Should I mention this on my CV? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should I mention any experience I have with children that isn't
>   formal work experience on my CV/resume?
>
> Should I mention this on my CV?

Your CV/resume is generally designed to showcase your relevant work experience and education. Since you "have no formal work experience in working with children", it will be tough to fit in your interactions with nephews and nieces.

You could write something in an "Other Interests" section, but this is rather weak. Wouldn't you imagine that every other candidate could write the same? Pretty much everyone has young relatives or neighbors and could write an "I like kids" paragraph.

I think your best bet is to expound on your experiences with your nephews and nieces in your cover letter, where you can be more conversational, and less formal.

Did you do something with them that mirrors almost exactly the kind of work you would be doing? If so, this is the place to explain. Did you do something unusual with your nephews and nieces that you think would make you unique among other candidates for the position? (Perhaps you babysat a bunch of them full-time for an entire summer while their parents were overseas.) If so, your cover letter would let you explain how valuable that experience would be in the position for which you are applying.

Whether you squeeze something into your CV/resume, or write about it more fully in your cover letter, make sure you tie it into the job. You want the reviewer to see that your experience would make you a good employee, not just a good Auntie or Uncle.

Answer (score 12):

My wife's a teacher.  In her mind "students" and "children she knows socially" are totally different.  She has different expectations of them, reacts to them differently, asks different things of them, etc.  I've seen this in other teachers as well.

I would leave the nephews & nieces off the CV and cover letter entirely.  In my opinion, it's better to present yourself as a "newbie ready to learn to do the job the way you want it done" than a "newbie who thinks he knows more than he really does".

The people interviewing you are probably experts - better to admit what you don't know and express a desire to learn than to claim you're at their level when they can clearly see otherwise.

Having said all that, Joe's answer brings up an important caveat: if you've done something with your relatives that would have *direct bearing* on the position you're applying for, then by all means mention it.